# C++ search pattern across 2 strings without concatenating them

Tags: c++, stl

I have:

```
std::string b;
std::string p;
const std::string sep;
```

`b` is buffer, `p` is packet (newly arrived bytes), `sep` is separator sequence, for example `\r\n\r\n`. I want to find position of next occurrence of separator in `b + p`, then move range `p.begin(), pos` from `p` to `b` without growing `b` more than necessary. If sep not found just append everything. Logically it looks like this:

```
std::string cc = b + p;
auto cc_pos = std::search(cc.begin(), cc.end(), sep.begin(), sep.end());
b = std::string(cc.begin(), atcc);
if (b.size() > MAX_BYTES) 
     throw std::runtime_error("packet too large");
if (cc_pos != cc.end())
    p = std::string(cc_pos + sep.size(), cc.end());
else
    p.clear();
```

But here I created temporary `cc` which has size `p.size() + b.size()`. How to do it efficiently (without allocating heap memory) and, if possible, elegantly? String `b` has `MAX_BYTES` reserved, so insertion is fast, but it should never allocate more than that.

Comment: Here solution depends on exact form of the separator. In case that is just 4 symbols, as in your example, you can just check if suffix of `b` is prefix of `sep` and then continue with searching in `p`. You know for certain that there is no full `sep` in `c` because you checked it on the previous iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can search the last *n* characters of `b` where *n* is the length of `sep`. If the sep sequence is found to start in the last *n* characters of `b` the second part of `sep` can be search for at the start of `p`.

Something like

```
int n = sep.size();
int remaining = n;

for (int i = 0; i < sep.size(); i++) {
    /* Search for entire sep at end of b
        if not found, search for sep minus last char
        then minus last 2 chars, 3 chars, and so on
    */
    auto it = std::search(b.end() - n - i, b.end(), sep.begin(), sep.end() - i);
    if (it != b.end()) {
        remaining = i; // number of sep chars to search for in p
        break;
    }
}

if (remaining > 0) {
    std::string sep_sub = sep.substr(n-remaining, remaining);
    std::string p_sub = p.substr(0, remaining);

    if (sep_sub == p_sub) {
        // Found sep split across b and p!
    }
}
```

This should check for an occurrence of `sep` spit across `b` and `p` without having to concat. The only additional memory used are the `sep_sub` and `p_sub` which combined will at most be of size `2 * (sizeof(sep) - 1)`.

This only checks that sep is split across b and p. You still need to check that the entirety of sep isn't in either b or p.

Comment: `int n = std::min(sep.size(), b.size())` or `b.end() - n` may involve UB

Comment: Agreed. Definitely check all the edge cases and handle any errors. I was just trying to get the major idea across.

Comment: It surely conveys the idea, so upvoted it. On the other hand it has bugs (initial `n` is incorrect, `- n` should be `- n + i` 1st loop, maybe more), so marking as an answer would be misleading. Anyway thanks for the suggestion.